# Doubts regarding qualcomm profiler

Tags: android, profiler, qualcomm

In the recent project, there is need to measure only camera fps and frame delay using the profiler distributed by qualcomm.
I have asked this in the Qualcomm forum also and went through their docs, but got no reply, so if anybody would give some guidance, that would be really helpful for me.

[image: real time trace mode of camera through Qualcomm profiler]

In the above snapshot, i have enabled only camera for tracing it in capture mode.
The issues I am currently facing are as follows,

1. From the above graph is it possible to measure the camera fps? And if so, how can it be achieved.
2. Is it possible by the profiler to see full pipeline from capturing to displaying.
3. What is the cam_strmdatapro shown in the snapshot, i have searched for that keyword, but found nothing related to it.
4. What are the green bars representing?
5. The fps supported by camera is 30, so per frame it should be taking around 33.33 ms per frame to capture.
   Assuming the green bars are representing the time to get data from camera, it is taking only 4-6 ms in avg. Why it is taking such lower duration when it should be around 33ms.
6. Are there any materials/tutorials to learn more about the profiler.

I have previously worked on linux environment and on opencv, but I am novice in the android world. I am trying to learn it as its required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.